# running hello.cpp tutorial, stuck at compiling WASM, abigen error, file read error

Tags: wasm, abigen

I'm running 3 cores confirmed on virtual machine (per solve for similar problem), and I'm still getting this error:

`~/eos$ eosio-cpp -abigen -o hello.wasm hello.cpp
error: error reading '/home/corey/eos/hello.cpp'
1 error generated.
Error while processing /home/corey/eos/hello.cpp.
abigen error`

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It says there is (likely) no file named `hello.cpp` in your `/home/corey/eos` directory.

Check the previous steps in the tutorial.
Find the step which was supposed to put this file there.
Find out what happened instead.

Comment: soooooooooooooooo...  that file path was there, and the file is there, but i couldnt replicate getting to it w cd.    ive been using command line interface for about 8 days now lol, im sure this would have been obvious to someone experienced.   i ran the abigen code from within the extant /hello directory and it worked instantly.   #HeadDesk.    tks for the redirecct Gassa!!